# Python ElasticSearch DSL: How to map String field that's not analyzed?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

The sample code still creates ES string field that's analyzed.

Tried this:

```
username = String(fields={'raw': String(index='not_analyzed')})
```

And this:

```
username = String(index="not_analyzed")
```

Comment: Having the same issue here. I also tried `username = String(analyzer="not_analyzed")`

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `<className>.init()` on the class where you're defining `username`. That should create the mappings in ES.

See http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html?highlight=init#document-life-cycle for more info.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest elasticsearch, `String` datatype is replaced by `Text` and `Keyword`

So for not analyze the string,

```py
from elasticsearch_dsl import Keyword

username = Keyword(index=False)
```

Comment: This seems to work. Is there any documentation around this? `elasticsearch-dsl` seems to have very limited documentation.